# Looping within a switch/case statement

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement, case

I've been playing around with basic Java and begun to create a project which includes a user input, system output ad a switch/case statement too. The user inputs a given animal and the system outputs the necessary noise that relates to the animal. At the moment the program asks the user once and then it is finished, however I want the user to be able to input as many animals as they'd like and get appropriate responses. Any help welcome, thanks. (I understand there may be some errors in my code, but I have only really just begun Java.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
String myString;
System.out.println("Enter your first animal: ");
myString = user_input.next();

loop: switch (myString) {

case "Cow":
    System.out.println("Mooo!");
    break;

case "Sheep":
    System.out.println("Baaaa!");
    break;

case "Mouse":
    System.out.println("Squeak Squeak!");
    break;

case "Horse":
    System.out.println("Neighhh!");
    break;

case "Goat":
    System.out.println("Skreachh!");
    break;

case "Fish":
    System.out.println("*Bubble Bubble*");
    break;

default:
    System.out.println("Invalid animal.");
    break;

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a while-loop, you cannot loop iver a switch statement.

Comment: Do you have any useful links to help me understand while-loops Tobias? Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Okay great, thanks again.

Comment: @Squiddie What do you mean by that? Not questioning it, I'd just looking for a better understanding. Also I have managed to fix the issue I had with the help of M. le Rutte who's comment is below, using a loop and condition.

Comment: @Squiddie Of course you can put a switch inside of a loop, but you cannot use loop only with switch itsself.

Answer (score 3):

You need a loop and a condition to stop.

```
while (true) {
    ...
    switch(...) {
       ....
       case "Stop":
         System.out.println("bye bye");
         System.exit(0);
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show me how to implement this into the code I have already provided?

Comment: ^ Not to worry - have implemented and works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `do-while` loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter your first animal: ");
            myString = input.next();
            switch (myString) {
                case "Cow":
                    System.out.println("Mooo!");
                    break;
                         ........
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid animal.");
                    break;
            }
        } while (!myString.equals("Stop"));
    }
```

You can get a well-explanation from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_do_while_loop.htm) and [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-do-while-loop)

Comment: Thanks for this, have you got any useful links I can use to learn a bit more on do-while loops?